# Button onclick function adds class to div

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to add the class '`.expanded`' to `#infoBox` when the user clicks on the button (which is located inside of the div), which have `onclick="expand"` on it.

```
<div id="infoBox" class="" onclick="expand">
    <aside>
        <h4>Kontakt</h4>
        <p>Har du brug for grafisk assistance, i form af råd og vejledning, eller brug for hjælp til design af grafik? Fyr mig en besked!</p>
    </aside>
                
    <button onClick="expand" class="primaryBtn noMovement">Kontakt</button>
</div>
```

After searching for solutions, I see a lot of jQuery-solutions, but isn't it possible to create with plain javascript?

Out of my noobie experience, I tried the following two javascript executions, but with no luck:

```
function expand() {
    document.getElementById("infoBox") {
        classList.add("expanded");
    }
}

function expand() {
    document.getElementsById("infoBox").classList.add("expanded");
}
```

Comment: You never call it `onClick="expand()"` There is no `getElementsById` Your first expand function makes no sense.

Comment: Get a linter on your IDE to catch errors

Comment: Your second `expand()` is reasonable, provided those elements exist. Your first `expand()` is invalid; `classList` here would be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is almost correct, you just need to modify `getElementsById` to `getElementById` (`Element` without `s`).

The way you're calling `onclick="expand"` need to be like `onclick="expand()"` (execute `expand` on `onclick` event).

```js
function expand() {
  document.getElementById("infoBox").classList.add("expanded");
}
```

```html
<div id="infoBox" class="" onclick="expand()">
  <aside>
    <h4>Kontakt</h4>
    <p>Har du brug for grafisk assistance, i form af råd og vejledning, eller brug for hjælp til design af grafik? Fyr mig en besked!</p>
  </aside>

  <button onClick="expand()" class="primaryBtn noMovement">Kontakt</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooo, I'm getting the hang of it!! :O Thank you for your help! Actually kinda weird I didn't notice the missing () in "expand()", since my nav menu uses onclick="openNav()" and onclick="closeNav()" to execute its apperance.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to add the "mystyle" class to the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is a working snippet from w3schools. get the element to a variable first

Comment: Yeah true, this is another way to do it. Thanks!